# iOS isn't executing the same code being executed in Android in Ionic4 App

Tags: javascript, ios, angular, typescript, ionic4

I'm executing the exact same code for iOS and Android.  Android is pushing the changes to firebase but iOS is not.

```js
  submit(itinerary: any) {
    console.log('submit itin', itinerary);
    this.dataSvc.checkUserItinerary(this.selection.id)
    .then((doc) => {
      if (doc.exists) {
        console.log('doc array', doc.data().array);
        console.log('doc', doc.data());
        // const test =  doc.data().likes.filter(x => x.myItineraryId === itinerary.id);

          console.log('found', itinerary);
          this.dataSvc.merge(itinerary.id, this.selection.id)
          .then(() => {
             this.dataSvc.addToDontShow(itinerary.id)
             .then(() => {
               this.filteredItineraries.splice(0, 1);
               if (!this.dontShowList.includes(itinerary.id)) {
                 this.dontShowList.push(itinerary.id);
                }
             });
          });
        }
    });
  }
```

```html
                <ion-item lines="none">
                    <ion-icon slot="end" name="thumbs-up" (click)="submit(filteredItineraries[0])"></ion-icon>
                </ion-item>
```

I'm not even getting the console logs for ios devices.  I'm not getting any error.  This is the only thing showing in xCode:
 Could not load IOSurface for time string. Rendering locally instead.

The odd thing is it's executing this piece of code inside of the method:

```
           if (!this.dontShowList.includes(itinerary.id)) {
             this.dontShowList.push(itinerary.id);
            }
```

Comment: There isn't enough information here to help you. How do you know what lines are being executed and what lines are not? Have you tried remote debugging?

Comment: By the console logs.  But I think i know the issue...I don't think the updated code is being distributed into xCode.  I didn't rebuild for ios before deploying to the ios device in xcode.  Trying that now

Comment: Hope you find the issue